# Select random URL on webpage using Chrome console

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, console

I'm trying to make a simple javascript command that I can run from the console in Chrome. I have a webpage which is filled with links that all follow the same format such as:

```
<a href="e/example.html">Example</a>
```

This would take it to www.site/e/example.html

I want to be able to randomly pick on of them and follow the link. I've tried doing it using a regex but can't work out how to use it in the console. Any help here would be appreciated!

This is the simple expression I made (just extracts the "e/example" part):

```
$ <a href="(.+?).html">.+?<\/a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTabName` and select all `a`-elements on page. I guess, it is resilient way than regexp.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. If anyone's wondering I did this and selected one randomly using the same method as others mentioned:
    var urls = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    this.document.location = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];

Answer (score 0):

First select all the links with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Then pick a random value, `randomIndex` returns an Integer between 0 and the array length.

```
let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
let randomLink = links[randomIndex].href;
```

`randomLink` should now contain a randomly chosen link on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to list all `a` elements using `document.querySelectorAll`. You can then loop through them and extract their `href` property like so:

```
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")].map(x => x.href);
```

Then just select a random element from this array:

```
const link = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
```